# can I host a WordPress website in my local host using the wordpress files

Tags: php, wordpress, web, localhost, hosting

I had a WordPress website working just fine . I downloaded the WordPress website files from cPanel , the files are :
bunch of php files , and three folders

1. wp-admin
2. wp-content
3. wp-includes

I really need to see the website design and content

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot. Because you don't have everything you need for it. Wordpress utilizes a mySQL database to store the actual content of the website.

So the first thing you need to do is go and download your sql information. This is fairly straightforward, but can be a pain if you're not familiar with the tools.

For example: if you're using Cpanel on your webhost, go to "phpMyAdmin" and then click on the database that starts "wp_" (note, if you have multiple wordpress installs, you'll have to figure out which database is the one you're looking for. try looking in the options table of each database for a sitename.).

Once you've clicked the database, click on Operations, and then Export.

You'll be able to download a sql file from there that you can import into a sql database elsewhere in order to view it on your localhost.  EllPro is right, using XAMPP or MAMP would allow you to do this. Same deal but in reverse to import the SQL information.

Problem is, now you need to go edit that database to tell it to point to the new location, which is more than I can just type out here.

Here's a link with a lot more information: https://wpengine.com/resources/migrate-wordpress-site/